# Забирать данные из рекламного кабинета Facebook с помощью Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

**Задача:** автоматически забирать данные из рекламного кабинета Facebook.

Есть приложение (facebook app) с доступом к рекламному аккаунту (`access level = development`).

В приложении добавлен product 'Marketing API'.

По `app_id` и `secret key` получен `access_token` через

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<secret>7&grant_type=client_credentials
```

вида `app_id|token`.

При попытке собрать insights:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_<ad_account_id>/insights/?access_token=<access_token>
```

Получаю

```
 "message": "Unsupported get request.",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
```

Если специально допустить ошибки в написании `<ad_account_id>` или `<access_token>` в ответ получаю соответствующие ошибки:

> "The account is invalid"
>
> "Invalid OAuth access token"

Явно что-то пропускаю, но не понимаю что. 
Буду признателен за любую помощь, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось созданием user-token, заместо app-token.